# Sort the list of Object having Null values in Hashmap

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, collections

I have to sort the object based on hashMap value inside the object.
The object is like :
Employee[getId, getName, getAge properties:{index,height, weight etc.}]
I want to sort the Employee based on Index values that is available in hashmap. While for index value Null may come sometime so I need to handle also.

I am trying the code below for sorting:

```
Comparator<GNode> com = Comparator.comparing(Employee::getProperty(Constans.INDEX), Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

But this is giving compile time errorr.

The Employee class is like :

```
public class Employee  
{
private UUID id;
private String name;
private int age;

public Employee(UUID id, String name, int age)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public UUID getId()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId(UUID id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}    

public int getAge()
{
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age)
{
    this.age = age;
}    
public Object getProperty(String key) {
    return properties.get(key);
}

public Object getProperty(String key, Object defValue) {
    Object ret = properties.get(key);
    return  (ret != null) ? ret : defValue;
}

public void addProperty(String key, Object value) {
    properties.put(key, value);
}
}
```

Please help me out from this issue.
Many many thanks to you in advance

Comment: `Employee::getProperty(Constans.INDEX)` is not valid Java syntax. If you can’t use a method reference, you have to use a lambda expression: `Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getProperty(Constans.INDEX), Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()))`, but it looks strange that you want to extract a property from an `Employee` class to get a comparator for comparing `GNode` instances.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a implementation of Comparator and make your rules, I did a example.

```
package com.ramiresmoreira;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Employee {
private UUID id;
private String name;
private int age;

public Employee(UUID id, String name, int age) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public UUID getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(UUID id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Employee with name equal null
    Employee e1 = new Employee(UUID.randomUUID(), "Name 1", 22);
    Employee e2 = new Employee(UUID.randomUUID(), null, 19);
    Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();
    employees.add(e1);
    employees.add(e2);
    List<Employee> sorted = employees.stream().sorted(new EmployeeSortNullFirst()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(sorted);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "name=" + name ;
}
}

class EmployeeSortNullFirst implements Comparator<Employee> {

@Override
public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
    if(e1 == null ||  e2 == null) {
        return 1;
    }
    return Integer.compare(getHash(e1), getHash(e2));
}

private int getHash(Employee e) {
    return hashAge(e) + hasName(e) + hashId(e);
} 

private int hasName(Employee e) {
    return e.getName() != null ? e.getName().hashCode() : Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}

private int hashAge(Employee e) {
    return e.getAge();
}

private int hashId(Employee e) {
    return e.getId() != null ? e.getId().hashCode() : Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Ramires, Thanks for reply, Actually i want to sort the object based on hashmap index values, Actually I am using below code
Collection.sort (list, new Comparator<Employee>() {
public int compare(Employee e1, Employeee2) {
return (Integer)e1.getProperty(Constants.INDEX).intValue()<(Integer)e2.getProperty(Constants.INDEX).intValue() ? -1 :(Integer)e1.getProperty(Constants.INDEX).intValue() ==(Integer)e2.getProperty(Constants.INDEX).intValue() ? 1 :0
}
});

But when e1.getProperty method returns null it is throwing NullPointerException.

Comment: You can try do 
`public Object getProperty(String key) {
         Object obj = properties.get(key);
         if(obj == null){
          return new Integer(0)
         }
         return  obj;
 }`

Comment: Apparently, “hansh”, “has”, and “hash” are all supposed to be a hash code, but what’s the purpose of sorting by a hash code? Randomization? Besides that, your comparator is broken. Return `1`, regardless of which element is `null` and also if both are `null`, is never valid.